# All 6 app delegate functions in swift 3 "nearly match optional requirement" - what is this? How to fix?

Tags: swift, appdelegate, swift3, xcode8

Downloaded the xcode 8.2 beta last night, converted most of my code but am now stuck with yellow warning symbols regarding the six functions of the app delegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

  func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
}
```

I am able to "fix" each function with either

```
  Rename to application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' to      satisfy this requirement

  Make 'application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)'       private to slince this warning
```

or

```
Add '@nonobjc' to silence this warning
```

considering I have not seen these three options before, would anyone mind explaining and any options to solve or disregard them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is all part of "renamification" and the Swift 3 change in the rules for the externalization of a method's first parameter.

So, do the first option: put in the `_` to make `_ application:` (instead of `application:` plain and simple) as the name of the first parameter in every case. Otherwise, the `application` will be externalized and Objective-C will see these methods as being called `applicationWithApplication...` which is not what you want to have happen.

Don't do either of the others. You don't want to *hide* these methods from Objective-C (`private` or `@nonobjc`); you want Objective-C to *see* them, and in particular to see them as the app delegate protocol methods.

Comment: Thank you for the continued explanation!

Comment: is it safe to leave the function as     "_ application:"

Comment: I'm surprised these didn't get fixed when you were running the migrator, but hey, at least you got them fixed now. You have to admit that the migrator is surprisingly good considering all it has to contend with.

Comment: Xcode 8 beta 6 changes the parameter type for `launchOptions`:


`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {}`

Comment: @M_G You do not write the `= nil` part when you implement it (you can, but it is a waste of space)

Comment: The auto-completion by Xcode adds the `= nil` part but you're right it's not necessary.

Comment: @M_G Yes, I regard that as a bug in the auto-completion. The template doesn't have it (and rightly).

Answer (score -1):

I had an instance where I had UITextViewDelegate in an extension but misspelled the class making it a redundant conformance.

Answer (score -3):

Here is how I fixed:

**OLD CODE:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

**NEW CODE:**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `applicationDidFinishLaunching` without launch options has been in iOS since iOS 2 and you are discouraged from using it in the apple docs.